# Is it possible to specify alternate path for storing "Conflict and Deleted" files in DFSR?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, .net, dfs, dfs-r

I have recently setup DFS replication between two folders and their subfolders on two 2012R2 servers. This folder is a "custom" folder used by our .NET web application that contains settings and data for our website. Content is not very relevant. I have DFS replication up and running, but it seems our application chokes on the "DfsrPrivate" folder that is created by DFS for staging and conflicted files. It is trivial to move the staging folder to a different directory, but I need to elimate DfsrPrivate from my replicated folder entirely. The dialog box provided by the GUI tool provides a path but no method to change this path.

[image: DFSR Replicated Folder Properties]

A google search has proven fruitless, as most answers revolve around "clearing out" this folder and not moving it entirely. I have also tried unchecking the "Move deleted files to Conflict and Deleted folder" to no avail.